# Vertical scroll issue in Ag-Grid 20.1.0 + Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, ag-grid, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify + Ag-grid 19.1.2 in my application and everything was fine until I decided to update ag-grid to version 20.1.0. With a new version the vertical scroll bar for ag-grid has gone and I have got a global one.

Here are identical examples with different versions of ag-grid

- version 20.1.0 - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBJBYj
- version 19.1.2 - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaBaaM

```
    <v-content>
        <v-container fluid fill-height>
            <v-layout>
                <v-flex>
                    <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-balham" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>  
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
       </v-container>
    </v-content>
```

Does some one know how to return the scroll bar back for version 20.1.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 20.2.0 has been released recently and that layout issue has gone. So simple upgrade to the newer version.